# Extjs Selection Model

Tags: extjs

I have a popup in an Editable grid for bulk update of details.

The update will be done for the rows selected.
I have entered the common data in a popup and i click on a button where i will update the json of the grid store and i close the popup.

when i go to the parent JSON for saving the details . it shows grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected().length as 0.

my code of js for popup is below:

```
var selectedRows = new Array();

var grid = parent.Ext.getCmp(gridName);
   var selection= grid.getSelectionModel(); 
   var items=[];
   for(i=0;i < grid.store.getCount();i++){  
      if(selection.isSelected(i)){

   selectedRows.push(i);
         }
         }


   parent.Ext.getCmp(gridName).getStore().loadRawData(JsonwithContent,false);

 for(var i=0;i<selectedRows.length;i++){
  sel_model_data.select(selectedRows[i],true);
  }
```

Now i need a solution for getting the selected rows again.

Comment: The problem is you're doing reload, not update of store records

Comment: Please let me know how to update rather than reloading

Comment: What is the "JsonwithContent" ? How do you get it?

Comment: Its is the Json to be updated in Store which i will get via an AJAX call